# Set multiple executable projects to a common output path in Windows 10 Desktop Bridge

Tags: visual-c++, uwp, windows-store, desktop-bridge, appx

I am looking for a way to combine all my "Applications" references into a common directory inside the AppX package. The project types of the references are standard Visual C++ (Win32) projects. The current structure of my solution is as follows:

**Solution Structure**

```
* Solution
|__ Exe_1 (Visual C++ Project)
|__ Exe_2 (Visual C++ Project)
|__ Exe_3 (Visual C++ Project)
|
|__ MyApp (AppX Project)
    |__ Applications
    |   |__ Exe_1
    |   |__ Exe_2
    |   |__ Exe_3
    |___ Images\
    |___ Package.appxmanifest
```

After publishing the solution and deploying the AppX package, I get the following directory structure:

**[ Actual ] Deployed AppX Directory Structure**

```
Com.MyApp.12107._cx40ttqa_n3.48019.0_x64zyj5
|__ Exe_1\Exe_1.exe
|__ Exe_2\Exe_2.exe
|__ Exe_3\Exe_3.exe
```

**[ Expected ] Deployed AppX Directory Structure**

```
Com.MyApp.12107._cx40ttqa_n3.48019.0_x64zyj5
|__ Exe_1.exe
|__ Exe_2.exe
|__ Exe_3.exe
```

**What I tried**

- I tried following [this guide on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-build-to-a-common-output-directory?view=vs-2019), but it didn't help for Visual C++-based projects.
- Changing the "Output directory" on executable's project properties didn't make any effect.
- Added a Post-Build Event in the AppX project to manually move the files.

**What I want to achieve**

A similar result to how Apple managed to pack iTunes' related files in the root app directory.

[image: iTunes App Package on Local machine]

---

UPDATE #1

I've edited the `MyApp.wapproj` file in the AppX project and modified the following lines:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Exe_1\Exe_1.vcxproj">
  <OutputItemType>Content</OutputItemType>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</ProjectReference>
```

With the modification in hand, the EXE is now *only* copied but not used as a real entry point. The case is similar to the Post-Build Event method.

Comment: I'm a little confused about how you changed the "Output directory"? If you set it to the path of appx folder, can it work? In addition, may I know why do you want to set executable projects to a common output path?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Regardless of the "Output Directory" of each Visual C++ project, the AppX project places each compiled executable project (including its references) are placed in correspondence to the project folder name. I.E. Suppose Foo is a Visual C++ EXE that is referenced from the AppX project, after generating and installing the package, the app directory would contain a folder called "Foo" that has the executable inside it. The goal of this question is to find a way to keep the contents of the "Foo" to remain in the root app directory rather than nested by the project name.

Comment: Based on your requirement, it is not feasible to keep the exe file directly in the root app.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT If so, how did iTunes manage to pack all their related files in to the root app directory? Please review the updated question.

Comment: However, it is not feasible in uwp apps.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT The app is Win32-based. Just like iTunes

Comment: By discussion, it is not possible in this scenario.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT FYI you can check the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of time of writing, Visual Studio 2019 (v16.6.4) doesn't offer a built-in option to change output paths for referenced "Applications". Alternatively, you have to revoke all Applications references from the projects and append the following under the imports of the assets in your `.wapproj` project file:

```
<Content Include="..\Path\To\Your\Exe_1\Exe_1.exe" />
<Content Include="..\Path\To\Your\Exe_2\Exe_2.exe" />
<Content Include="..\Path\To\Your\Exe_3\Exe_3.exe" />
```

Additionally, you will need to replace the the tag `<EntryPointProjectUniqueName>` with `<EntryPointExe>` since we're not dealing with referenced applications anymore (at least in the author's case.)

```
<EntryPointExe>..\Path\To\Your\Exe_1\Exe_1.exe</EntryPointExe>
```

Finally, you will obtain an output similar to the expectation stated by the author after deploying it to a machine.

---

**Feedback from Microsoft**

> As you can imagine there is a reason that we do this and the primary
> concern is duplicate filenames as well as some issues with uploading
> to the store. As of now there is no override that we provide that will
> allow you to achieve this although there are some hacks you could do
> to make it possible but it is not advised.​
>
> Scoban [MSFT]

The discussion can be found [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1110232/set-multiple-executable-projects-to-a-common-outpu.html).